# How do I install ubuntu-desktop?

Tags: data-recovery

The ubuntu-desktop in synaptic is removed on my system. And when I start the machine, I cannot login ,the mouse and keyboard cannot be used also. How to fix it? How to enter the text mode of ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the recovery mode in the grub screen (if it doesn't show up, keep pressed the shift key during boot). Then if you can login as root, try to install again ubuntu-desktop (this may install missing packages). If only "ubuntu-desktop" package was removed, then it should be other problem, as it is a meta-package which is not essential (can be removed safety).

Comment: I cant login as root in that mode. The system stop there when inits..Is there any other method?

Comment: @Jinx: Does the grub menu shows? What happen if you use the Live CD? does it works? If you don't have any special files to recover, I suggest you to reinstall the system (could be faster). If you need to recover files, enter with the Live CD and mount your drive, then copy your files into a USB or something. If you want to fix the installation, then Other way is to use the Alternate CD of the same version you have installed (you can find it here:http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/alternative-download), then choose the bootup option "rescue a broken system.". Hope it helps.